# resize a div element according to its content without jscript

Tags: html, css, resize

I can not get a div that is created dynamically based on their content is resized. The idea that having a principial div (# divPrincipal) having a fixed width. Within this div, among other things will be another div (# divCabecera) which is to be resized according to their content. Finally, inside # divCabecera they will be created any number of div with text (# divTexto).

here it is the basic css:

```
# divTexto{
  border-right: 1px solid #cdcdcd;
  height: 100%;
  width: 33%;
  float: left;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

[image]

All I need  is that they appear more blue div's,  the red area  grow to the black area. after that display a scroll

I hope you can help me

Comment: sorry, the red div can grow as he wants but only shows the visible area for the black div, then when the red div is bigger than the black div it must show a scroll

Comment: can  you set up a working sample on fiddle?

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you're going for. Not sure but this is what I got.

http://jsfiddle.net/gulfarazyasin/BQfN3/

```
div#container {
    border: 1px solid black;
    height: 250px;
    width: 300px;
    overflow: auto;
    white-space: nowrap;
}

div#container div#divTexto {
    border: 1px solid blue;
    height: 200px;
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 0 20px;
}

div#red {
    border: 1px solid red;
    margin: 10px;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

Add/Remove #divTexto to see the desired effect